# Better way to fix [regexp-replace] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [regexp-replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regexp-replace) tag is for:

> Oracle function that extends the functionality of the REPLACE function by allowing searching a string for a regular expression pattern

from this I deduce that every question under this tag must be related to Oracle and have an [oracle] tag, but this is not always true for several reasons:

1. the `regexp_replace` function is common to other "DBMS"

   - MySql
   - PostgreSQL
   - Hive
   - Apache Spark
2. there are other programming languages that have similar functions with similar names

   - Matlab - `regexprep`
   - PHP - `preg_replace`
   - G-Suite / Autohokey- `REGEXREPLACE`
3. it is a common problem to replace the match of a regex, so people insert wrongly this tag

How to fix these issues?

In my opinion we should take these actions:

1. rewrite the tag info of [regexp-replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regexp-replace) to include in the tag every question regarding functions at the point 1. above
2. create a tag for each function

   - Matlab - `regexprep` ([134 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regexprep+%5Bmatlab%5D+is%3Aquestion))
   - PHP - `preg_replace` (existing tag [preg-replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preg-replace) with [500 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/preg-replace)(?))
   - G-Suite / Autohotkey - `REGEXREPLACE` ([189 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=Relevance&pagesize=50&q=REGEXREPLACE%20is%3Aquestion))
3. remove the tag [regexp-replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regexp-replace) in unrelated questions and substitute it with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/replace)

Is this a real problem? Are the above steps the right way to fix it?